openldap check_password is not loading
I am attempting to get password policy working along with the default check module (/usr/lib64/openldap/check_password.so) that ships with openldap package for Amazon Linux 2023.  I have been able to get the password policy working correctly without the module but when I delete the policy and then add it back with the check module set, slapd complains that it cannot find the shared_object:

slapd[471944]: check_password_quality: lt_dlopen failed: (check_password) file not found.

I've attempted to place soft links to /usr/lib64/openldap/check_password.so in /usr/lib/openldap, /usr/lib, /usr/bin and /usr/sbin with no success.  I cannot find any documentation on the check_password.so implementation that ships with this distribution.

The problem was that I was not specifying the full file name of the check_password shared object.  It should be:
pwdCheckModule: check_password.so

instead of:
pwdCheckModule: check_password

It appears to be working now.
